# How to pull the number of people that attended 5 or more unqiue events in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL and want to pull all the people in my database that have attended more than five events with us this year. 
All events have unique names( eg.Event1, Event2, Event3) 
If someone purchased more than one ticket to the event, there are multiple records in the database for that person because it details things like their seat number, so it needs to be based on the event name and not the number of records for that person.

```
 Select AccountID, Name, Event
 From EventInfo 
 Where Year = 2020
```

So need added the condition that the person attended more than 5 distinct Events. If anyone could help, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select name
from t
where year = year(getdate())
group by name
having count(distinct event) >= 5;
```